# How to move parts of an array to the front?

Tags: java

So I had to use an array to add Aliens into my program, and now I am supposed to move all the parts that are "null" to the front, so instead of printing out Alien 1: blah blah, Alien 2: null, Alien 3: null, Alien 4 blah blah, I need it to have Alien 1 blah blah, Alien 2 blah blah.

I know how to do the remove feature in an array list, but am not sure how to figure this out with just a simple array.

```
public void consolidate() {
    for (int index = 0; index < cockpitCrew.length; index++) {
        if (cockpitCrew[index] == null) {

        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I have so far for the "removal" of the null array objects.

EDIT: Basically I need it to skip over the nulls when it prints out in this loop

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You have an array which is fixed in size. You can't "remove" `null` entries.

Comment: @Garzhod if you just want to skip over the nulls change your if statement to `if (cockpitCrew[index] != null)`. I'm not sure I'm understanding your question correctly? Do you not want to "skip" the elements but rearrange the elements so that ones with null value are at the front? If so I think this is more of a sorting problem.

Comment: Don't ever delete your question and replace it with "Has been solved."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is create another array and add the objects to it. 
Keep two indexes rear and front. When you meet a null object add it to `rear`, when you meet a not null object add it to `front`. Thus at the end you will have null objects at the rear of the array and not null objects at the front of the array.

```
public void consolidate() {
    Alien newAlienArray[] = new Alien[cockpitCrew.length];
    int front = 0;
    int rear = cockpitCrew.length - 1;
    for (int index = 0; index < cockpitCrew.length; index++) {
        if (cockpitCrew[index] == null) {
            newAlienArray[rear] = cockpitCrew[index];
            rear--;
        } else {
            newAlienArray[front] = cockpitCrew[index];
            front++;
        }
    }
    cockpitCrew = newAlienArray;// if you finally need to replace the new order in cockpitCrew
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your if statement, you just need to find the first non-null array element starting at that spot (you'll need a loop for that) and then write some code to swap positions of those elements.

If you don't find a non-null array element, you can safely terminate your loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your approach, but here is how I would solve this problem...

```
// Make it static, let's not rewrite the Array in place...
public static Alien[] consolidate(Alien[] cockpitCrew) {
  List<Alien> al = new ArrayList<Alien>(); // Create a List to hold the Alien(s).
  for (Alien alien : cockpitCrew) {        // Use a for-each loop over the cockpitCrew.
    if (alien != null) {                   // Test for null.
      al.add(alien);
    }
  }
  return al.toArray(new Alien[al.size()]); // Return a new Array.
}
```

Comment: I am using an array and arraylist. I just need the array to print out with no null objects; I figured it out on the array list

Answer (score 0):

There is different method to solve this problem:

- You can use the same array 
  in the same array is similar a "bubble sorting", if "cockpitCrew[index] == null" change it with the next array element, for this you can use 2 index. First index for current element e second index for the next and eventually a swap variable.
- You Can use 2 different array
  this is very simple method, if (cockpitCrew[index] <> null),  you copy this element (not null) in the 1st array otherwise "cockpitCrew[index] == null"  copy it at the 2nd array .

I think that is not very difficult.